# How Do I Develop a Basic Android App Showing remote Data in TStringGrid (Firebird)

Tags: database, delphi

I've been trying to get a basic Android app to show some data in a `TStringGrid` using Delphi 11.

When running the app on my Samsung Galaxy, I am getting the data into a `TEdit` and into a `TComboBox`, so it would appear I got the connection to the database right, but the StringGrid shows nothing. Also, the navigator shows all buttons are disabled.

Strangely, at design time, regardless of the selected output device (master, Android, or iOS) data is shown in the `TStringGrid` and the navigator appears to be alive too.

For now, I'm using the Community Edition. The connection is to a remote FB database over the Internet.

Is there a solid sample that I could examine? All the ones I found at Embarcadero or GitHub either don't compile or show similar issues of no data in the TStringGrid. I already spent well over a week compiling, testing, and reading other people's code but still no solution in sight.

I want to show data in the `TStringGrid` with the use of `TBindSource`.

Comment: This is a code site, so please post minimal application code and we can help.

Comment: In community edition of Delphi only connecting to local database is supported.  In order to be able to connect to remote database you need at least Enterprise edition. You can red more at [Product editions](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/product-editions)

Comment: Remote database is a bad idea alternative is to use a REST Server and connect to it . Anyway, you can install ZEOSLib to connect a Firebird Database (https://sourceforge.net/p/zeoslib/wiki/How%20to%20use%20Firebird%204.0%20with%20Zeos%20on%20Android/).

Comment: As others have mentioned you can't do so with the Community Ed. However I want to offer advise.
The general rule is not to expose your database to the outside world. Anyone can decompile your application and get the login information etc and mess up your database. You should be using a middleman such as a rest server. So in theory it will look like this: `DATABASE <-> REST SERVER <-> YOUR APPLICATION`. The rest server can also help you process data before it goes to the database. I suggest looking up on how to create and work with REST.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I did have my doubts abut connectivity using the CE but the thing is the app does connect to a remote database and I can see the data in some of the components linked via TBindSource. Just not the StringGrid. I cn also see the data in the TStringGrid when running as Win32.

I guess I will have to get the Enterprise trial to make sure I can do what I need.

As for the security, this is for just one company and not to see the light of day outside of it. A simple road patrol app (looking for potholes and such) for a small municipality.